# Regex capture all dot characters excluding the dot character in front of '.com' in an email

Tags: regex, email

Looking to do the following with regex using this email: `tes.t+yolo@gmail.com`

- capture all `.` characters excluding the `.` that's in front of .`com`

In addition:

- capture everything from `+` up to but not including the `@` character

The final result would look like: `test@gmail.com`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand your approach was to remove the matched parts from the string in order to receive the final result. You would then need to do this in two steps (with two regex) - remove the dots, and remove the part between `+` and `@`.

[Regex](https://regex101.com/r/lZDV02/9) to capture all `.` except before `.com`: `\.(?!com$)`

[Regex](https://regex101.com/r/lZDV02/3) to capture everything from `+` up to not including the `@` character: `\+[^@]*`

**You can use these together as a single regex expression: `\+[^@]*|\.(?!com$)`**

[image]

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lZDV02/10)

**Bonus**

Alternatively, another [approach](https://regex101.com/r/lZDV02/4) would be to tackle this through groups, e.g:

```
^([^\.]+)(.)([^+]+)([^@]+)(\S+)$
```

You can then build the final result by combining several groups together.

[image]